# How do I select a select box with javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms

How does one select, or focus, a `<select>` box using javascript? `.select()` works fine for selecting inputs with jQuery, but it does nothing for select boxes. Trying to select the currently selected option doesn't work either.

**Update:**
People are misunderstanding the question two ways.

1. First this is not a duplicate of how to select a text input. As I already stated, the usual method that works for selecting a text box does not work.
2. I am not trying to retrieve or set the selected index of a select box. I just want the select box in general to be *selected*, like when you are tabbing through a form.

**Update 2:**

OK, I figured out what the problem was which makes the question moot. Due to a quirk of testing from the Chrome console, `.focus()` did nothing, which made me believe it was useless. I guess that is why I had ended up using `.select()` which visibly worked when I tested from the Chrome console, but didn't work for select boxes. When I tried `.focus()` from a javascript file then it worked. I guess when the Chrome console is in focus then you can't focus stuff with in the actual page programatically. Lesson learned.

Comment: `selectElement.selectedIndex = 2`? Do you mean checkboxes?

Comment: Samples - html, and script that you have tried would be helpful.

Comment: try setting selectedIndex: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-select-selectedindex

Comment: I am not trying to choose a option within the select box, I am trying to do the equivalent of jQuery's `.select()` method. Which focuses the select box, like when you are tabbing through a form.

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Comment: Why is the question being downvoted?

Comment: @Moss it is absolutely a duplicate, use `.focus()`. `.select()` does NOT select a text box at all, it selects the text within it.  Even if you can't see that the object is focused it is.  Literally google ".focus javascript" and look at the w3schools example changing the element from an anchor to a select box works.

Comment: @Moss also, `.select()` is JS not jQuery,`.select(callback)` is jQuery and is an event handler, not even related to what you are trying to do, honestly try to use Google before asking why your question is being downvoted

Comment: @NickA, I did use Google and found no answers, I also found no answers in StackOverflow, that is why I asked the question. Don't be insulting.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `focus()` method.

- The `focus()` method is used to give focus to an element (if it can
  be focused).

**Example:**

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <select id="mySelect">
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
      <option>Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <script>
        function Function() {
           document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex.focus();    
        }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this an answer to my question?

Comment: "Trying to select the currently selected option doesn't work either."? don't you want to retrieve the selected index of that particular option?

Comment: No, I want to select the select box.

Comment: @Moss I apologise can you please re-update your description, there seems to be ambiguity with how you structured your description.

Comment: I added the word "focus", to try to make it clearer than it already is.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex = "2";
```

From W3C:

**The selectedIndex property sets (or returns) the index of the selected option in a drop-down list.**

The index starts at 0.

Note: If the drop-down list allows multiple selections it will only return the index of the first option selected.

Note: The value "-1" will deselect all options (if any).

Note: If no option is selected, the selectedIndex property will return -1.

So, to set it, assign the property selectedIndex to the numeric index of  you want to choose.

**OR you can use**

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").value = "foo";
```

and set the value property to the name of the option you want.

You may also want to check out the Select DOM object page on W3C here:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp

Comment: Please read the question again. I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Moss if you want to select or focus on a select element, you can use [`.focus()`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/). I made a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dawchihliou/ocpd1kx6/) so you can see it more clearly.

Comment: Please read the question again. I updated it.

Comment: Hey are you saying that you want the <select> to be focused and show the list of options?

Comment: I update my answer as well. Focusing on a select element can be done with jquery [`.focus()`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/). But showing the list of options of the select element is trickier and I don't have a quick solution